# Cent get LevelMatchFilter to work

Tags: .net, log4net

I created a custom appender to log errors to a DB using EF. I also have a RollingFileAppender that I want to log everything.This is my config section:

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender"
          type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="c:\logs\log-file.txt" />
      <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="1MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline"/>
    </appender>
    <appender name="LogToDBAppender" type="Common.Appender.LogToDBAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
        <levelToMatch value="ERROR"/>
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <root level="ALL">      
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogToDBAppender" />
    </root>    
  </log4net>
```

The problem here is that the following code:

```
logger.Info("Entering LoadAllUsers");
```

calls the LogToDBAppender class, and of course it fails because it is expecting an exception parameter.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `DenyAllFilter` after the `LevelMatchFilter`

```
<appender name="LogToDBAppender" type="Common.Appender.LogToDBAppender">
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
    <levelToMatch value="ERROR"/>
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
</appender>
```

The first filter accepts all ERROR messages and the second rejects all other messages. Without the second filter the other messages also get accepted.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and could only make it work with another RollingFileAppender. If I implement it in my LogToDBAppender it doesn't make any difference...it still kicks in for INFO level logs.

Comment: Does your appender derive from the AppenderSkeleton? The appender needs to implement filtering or else it does not work.